# Insert order details from XML into SQL database table

Tags: sql-server, xml, xquery

I want to insert this XML file (API Response) into a database table as columns. when the response consist of two different items for unique order id, order id column should be inserted for both different items.

Here is the result that should be like this :

```
row #1  order id: i6tp-pucp-dsrx-1gg7-ikef  item_no: 2304
row #2  order id: i6tp-pucp-dsrx-1gg7-ikef  item_no: 10914
```

Here is the response which I get from an API in XML form:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"? ><ns1:result xmlns:ns1="url.xsd">
<ns1:orders>
    <ns1:order>
        <ns1:code>i6tp-pucp-dsrx-1gg7-ikef</ns1:code>
        <ns1:status>CONFIRMED</ns1:status>
        <ns1:date>2022-11-30T20:50:36.920</ns1:date>
        <ns1:deliveryAddress>
            <ns1:firstName>fname</ns1:firstName>
            <ns1:lastName>lastname</ns1:lastName>
            <ns1:streetname>streetname </ns1:streetname>
            <ns1:streetnumber>stno</ns1:streetnumber>
            <ns1:town>town</ns1:town>
            <ns1:postalCode>PLZ</ns1:postalCode>
            <ns1:gender>FEMALE</ns1:gender>
            <ns1:deliveryAddressType>address</ns1:deliveryAddressType>
        </ns1:deliveryAddress>
        <ns1:paymentAddress>
            <ns1:firstName>fname</ns1:firstName>
            <ns1:lastName>lastname</ns1:lastName>
            <ns1:streetname>streetname </ns1:streetname>
            <ns1:streetnumber>stno</ns1:streetnumber>
            <ns1:town>town</ns1:town>
            <ns1:postalCode>PLZ</ns1:postalCode>
            <ns1:gender>FEMALE</ns1:gender>
        </ns1:paymentAddress>
        <ns1:currency>EUR</ns1:currency>
        <ns1:entries>
            <ns1:entry>
                <ns1:sku>2304</ns1:sku>
                <ns1:quantity>1</ns1:quantity>
                <ns1:basePrice>18.49</ns1:basePrice>
                <ns1:totalBasePrice>18.49</ns1:totalBasePrice>
                <ns1:merchantSubTotal>18.49</ns1:merchantSubTotal>
                <ns1:totalPrice>18.49</ns1:totalPrice>
                <ns1:name>ArtNo1</ns1:name>
                <ns1:taxClass>at-vat-full</ns1:taxClass>
                <ns1:warehouse>001-default-warehouse</ns1:warehouse>
            </ns1:entry>
            <ns1:entry>
                <ns1:sku>10914</ns1:sku>
                <ns1:quantity>1</ns1:quantity>
                <ns1:basePrice>49.99</ns1:basePrice>
                <ns1:totalBasePrice>49.99</ns1:totalBasePrice>
                <ns1:merchantSubTotal>49.99</ns1:merchantSubTotal>
                <ns1:totalPrice>49.99</ns1:totalPrice>
                <ns1:name>Artno2</ns1:name>
                <ns1:taxClass>at-vat-full</ns1:taxClass>
                <ns1:warehouse>001-default-warehouse</ns1:warehouse>
            </ns1:entry>
        </ns1:entries>
        <ns1:cancelOrders/>
        <ns1:returnOrders/>
        <ns1:delayOrders/>
        <ns1:consignments/>
        <ns1:totalBasePrice>68.48</ns1:totalBasePrice>
        <ns1:merchantDiscountTotal>0</ns1:merchantDiscountTotal>
        <ns1:merchantSubTotal>68.48</ns1:merchantSubTotal>
        <ns1:marketplaceDiscountTotal>0</ns1:marketplaceDiscountTotal>
        <ns1:subtotal>68.48</ns1:subtotal>
        <ns1:deliveryCost>0.0</ns1:deliveryCost>
        <ns1:paymentCost>0.0</ns1:paymentCost>
        <ns1:totalPrice>68.48</ns1:totalPrice>
        <ns1:paymentMode>payment</ns1:paymentMode>
        <ns1:deliveryMode>E+2</ns1:deliveryMode>
        <ns1:additionalDeliveryOption>E2_1</ns1:additionalDeliveryOption>
        <ns1:deliveryConfiguration>Post</ns1:deliveryConfiguration>
        <ns1:shipmentDate>2022-12-02T07:00:11.680</ns1:shipmentDate>
        <ns1:estimatedDeliveryDate>2022-12-06T07:00:11.680</ns1:estimatedDeliveryDate>
        <ns1:avisoData>
            <ns1:address>
                <ns1:line>line1</ns1:line>
                <ns1:line>line2</ns1:line>
                <ns1:line>line3</ns1:line>
            </ns1:address>
            <ns1:phone>0123456789</ns1:phone>
            <ns1:email>info@gmail.com</ns1:email>
        </ns1:avisoData>
    </ns1:order>
</ns1:orders></ns1:result>
```

Comment: XML support is **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for editing my question. yes I am using sql -server

Comment: Your XML contains **XML namespace prefixes** `ns1:` in your elements - but you don't show us how that XML namespace is defined ...... that's a critical part of the solution - can you add this to your question, please?

Comment: before order it has just <ns1:result></ns1:result>
I dont know why it does not allow me to edit my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this - obviously, as mentioned - I don't *know* what your XML namespace declaration looks like, so I've just *faked* it here - adapt as needed....

```
DECLARE @Data XML = 
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns1:orders xmlns:ns1="urn:somenamespace">
    <ns1:order>
        <ns1:code>i6tp-pucp-dsrx-1gg7-ikef</ns1:code>
        <ns1:status>CONFIRMED</ns1:status>
        <ns1:date>2022-11-30T20:50:36.920</ns1:date>
        <ns1:deliveryAddress>
            <ns1:firstName>fname</ns1:firstName>
            <ns1:lastName>lastname</ns1:lastName>
            <ns1:streetname>streetname </ns1:streetname>
            <ns1:streetnumber>stno</ns1:streetnumber>
            <ns1:town>town</ns1:town>
            <ns1:postalCode>PLZ</ns1:postalCode>
            <ns1:gender>FEMALE</ns1:gender>
            <ns1:deliveryAddressType>address</ns1:deliveryAddressType>
        </ns1:deliveryAddress>
        <ns1:paymentAddress>
            <ns1:firstName>fname</ns1:firstName>
            <ns1:lastName>lastname</ns1:lastName>
            <ns1:streetname>streetname </ns1:streetname>
            <ns1:streetnumber>stno</ns1:streetnumber>
            <ns1:town>town</ns1:town>
            <ns1:postalCode>PLZ</ns1:postalCode>
            <ns1:gender>FEMALE</ns1:gender>
        </ns1:paymentAddress>
        <ns1:currency>EUR</ns1:currency>
        <ns1:entries>
            <ns1:entry>
                <ns1:sku>2304</ns1:sku>
                <ns1:quantity>1</ns1:quantity>
                <ns1:basePrice>18.49</ns1:basePrice>
                <ns1:totalBasePrice>18.49</ns1:totalBasePrice>
                <ns1:merchantSubTotal>18.49</ns1:merchantSubTotal>
                <ns1:totalPrice>18.49</ns1:totalPrice>
                <ns1:name>ArtNo1</ns1:name>
                <ns1:taxClass>at-vat-full</ns1:taxClass>
                <ns1:warehouse>001-default-warehouse</ns1:warehouse>
            </ns1:entry>
            <ns1:entry>
                <ns1:sku>10914</ns1:sku>
                <ns1:quantity>1</ns1:quantity>
                <ns1:basePrice>49.99</ns1:basePrice>
                <ns1:totalBasePrice>49.99</ns1:totalBasePrice>
                <ns1:merchantSubTotal>49.99</ns1:merchantSubTotal>
                <ns1:totalPrice>49.99</ns1:totalPrice>
                <ns1:name>Artno2</ns1:name>
                <ns1:taxClass>at-vat-full</ns1:taxClass>
                <ns1:warehouse>001-default-warehouse</ns1:warehouse>
            </ns1:entry>
        </ns1:entries>
        <ns1:cancelOrders/>
        <ns1:returnOrders/>
        <ns1:delayOrders/>
        <ns1:consignments/>
        <ns1:totalBasePrice>68.48</ns1:totalBasePrice>
        <ns1:merchantDiscountTotal>0</ns1:merchantDiscountTotal>
        <ns1:merchantSubTotal>68.48</ns1:merchantSubTotal>
        <ns1:marketplaceDiscountTotal>0</ns1:marketplaceDiscountTotal>
        <ns1:subtotal>68.48</ns1:subtotal>
        <ns1:deliveryCost>0.0</ns1:deliveryCost>
        <ns1:paymentCost>0.0</ns1:paymentCost>
        <ns1:totalPrice>68.48</ns1:totalPrice>
        <ns1:paymentMode>payment</ns1:paymentMode>
        <ns1:deliveryMode>E+2</ns1:deliveryMode>
        <ns1:additionalDeliveryOption>E2_1</ns1:additionalDeliveryOption>
        <ns1:deliveryConfiguration>Post</ns1:deliveryConfiguration>
        <ns1:shipmentDate>2022-12-02T07:00:11.680</ns1:shipmentDate>
        <ns1:estimatedDeliveryDate>2022-12-06T07:00:11.680</ns1:estimatedDeliveryDate>
        <ns1:avisoData>
            <ns1:address>
                <ns1:line>line1</ns1:line>
                <ns1:line>line2</ns1:line>
                <ns1:line>line3</ns1:line>
            </ns1:address>
            <ns1:phone>0123456789</ns1:phone>
            <ns1:email>info@gmail.com</ns1:email>
        </ns1:avisoData>
    </ns1:order>
</ns1:orders>';
```

Use this SQL query using the SQL Server XQuery support to get at your data items:

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES('urn:somenamespace' AS ns1)
SELECT
    OrderNo = xc.value('(ns1:code)[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
    ItemNo = xc2.value('(ns1:sku)[1]', 'int')
FROM
    @Data.nodes('/ns1:orders/ns1:order') AS XT(XC)
CROSS APPLY
    XC.nodes('ns1:entries/ns1:entry') AS XT2(XC2)
```

This returns a result of:

```
OrderNo                     ItemNo
-----------------------------------
i6tp-pucp-dsrx-1gg7-ikef     2304
i6tp-pucp-dsrx-1gg7-ikef    10914
```

Comment: how I can also add a column beside Order no with rowno like this :
RowNo      OrderNo                     ItemNo
---------------------------------------------
1            i6tp-pucp-dsrx-1gg7-ikef     2304
1            i6tp-pucp-dsrx-1gg7-ikef    10914

Comment: I solve it already by adding DENSE_RANK() 
thanks